# jQuery Datatables not serializing more than 1000 records

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery Datatable that renders 1500 rows at the client side.  My User checks the rows and then I send the Ids of selected rows and save the data.

This is working fine for the first 1000 rows but any time more than that is checked the data does not seem to be getting posted - on Dev Tools the call to MVC controller shows a 500 internal server error but with a breakpoint on the method it doesn't get hit?

If I have 1000 rows selected the breakpoint gets hit and all 1000 ids are passed.  Once I add 1 more row to be checked the breakpoint doesn't get hit but I see 500 internal server error on Dev Tools?

My code is below:

```
  $('#saveBtn').click(function () {
    var dataArr = [];
    var rows = $('tr.selected');
    var rowData = myTable.rows({ selected: true }).data();

    $.each($(rowData), function (key, value) {
      dataArr.push(value[0]); //Id is hidden in 1st column of the table
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '@Url.Action("SaveData", "MyController")',
      data: JSON.stringify(dataArr),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (data) {
        location.reload();
      },
      error: function () {
        sweetAlert("Error Occurred Saving");
        location.reload();
      },
    });
  });
```

My MVC Controller is pretty straight forward

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(List<int> Ids)
{
  //private method that just calls to the DB and sets a flag to say that Id was checked
  SaveData(Ids);

  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);  
}
```

I have tried to add the below to my MVC Web config but I still dont get breakpoint hit when I select more than 1000

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Try setting the maxjsonlength property to a higher value. Thanks.

Comment: a higher value than what I have as 2147483644 - isn't that the max value it can be?

Comment: where you could set the collection size? seems like it is limited to 1000

Comment: The value is correct. Where have you placed the breakpoint - in SaveData  function? If so, could you post the code or check if it catches any error

Comment: really dumb question but do you have pagination enabled on your datatable?

Comment: @Travis...i am using client side paging just

Comment: @nagaraj - breakpoint placed on the curly brace on the MVC action...gets hit and passes 1000 ids in my first scenario and doesn't get hit when I pass 1001 even though developer tools shows it getting a 500 server error..with a breakpoint set would have thought it still should hit the method

Comment: Would it be an idea to call the ajax request with batches of 500 selected rows?  What would be best way to do that?

Comment: It is good to identify why you are getting an internal server error. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942031/-http-error-500.0-internal-server-error-error-when-you-you-open-an-iis-7.0-webpage

Comment: Can you add this into your config just for fun: 

<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>

Comment: Just send the array of ints instead of creating a JSON string from them

Comment: @jb06 would that be just data : dataArr ?  And MVC should just bind that to the controller parameter?

Comment: Yes, try that, the fact that you aren't hitting the controller action at all when you set a breakpoint makes me think your parameter isn't binding correctly. You will have to change your contentType too

Comment: @JB06 - ill give it a try but as I say it binds fine if the number of rows selected is 10 or 80 or 1000..its only when I get to the 1001 threshold.  What epuld the datatype need changed too?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat Just remove the contentType altogether

Comment: @TravisActon - adding to your config just for fun: <appSettings> <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers did indeed fix the issue - if you want to add that as an answer ill mark it as accepted

Comment: Thanks, actually did not know it had that default setting for security until I dug into your issue so glad I was able to learn that as well for future development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding  to your appSettings element in configuration overrides default max limit as ASP.NET rejects request if they contain more than 1000 elements due to security concerns.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 1):

One of the way we can resolve the issue is specifying the maxlength of the json result in the c#.
**Example:-**

```
jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = 999999999;
return  jsonResult
```